# Why form validations are not working with jquery.validation.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation

I'm trying out a new plugin which is called jquery.validation.js and it seems that after I try to apply them it doesn't work. Can someone kindly help me on this?

Here's the page.html

```
<form id="CustomerForm" class="form-horizontal group-border stripped" name="CustomerDetails">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 control-label">Customer Name</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9">
            <input type="text" ng-model="CusDetails.cname" class="form-control" name="cname" id="cname"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--end of .form-group-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 control-label">Company Name</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9">
            <input type="text" ng-model="CusDetails.comname" class="form-control" name="comname"id="comname" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--end of .form-group-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 control-label" for="">Telephone Number</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9">
            <div class="input-group input-icon">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone s16"></i></span>
                <input ng-model="CusDetails.tel" class="form-control" name="ctel" type="text" placeholder="(999) 999-9999" id="ctel">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End .form-group  -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 control-label" for="">Email address</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9">
            <input ng-model="CusDetails.email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="someone@example.com" id="email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End .form-group  -->
</form>
div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                    <button name="btnSubmit" type="submit" ng-click="AddCustomer()" class="btn btn-info pad"><span class="fa fa-user-plus"></span> Add Customer</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="cancel" class="btn btn-default pad">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here's what the angular.controller.js looks

```
function AddCustomerController($scope, $location, $rootScope, $http, CustService) {

        (function initController() {


        })();



        $scope.AddCustomer = function () {

            var CustomerDetails = {
                cname: $scope.CusDetails.cname,
                comname: $scope.CusDetails.comname,
                tel: $scope.CusDetails.tel,
                email: $scope.CusDetails.email

            };

            CustService.Customer(CustomerDetails, function (res) {
                console.log(res);

                $.extend($.gritter.options, {
                    position: 'bottom-right',
                });

                if (res.data == 'success') {
                    $.gritter.add({

                        title: 'Success!',
                        text: 'Successfully added the new customer ' + '<h4><span class="label label-primary">' + CustomerDetails.cname + '</span></h4>',
                        time: '',
                        close_icon: 'l-arrows-remove s16',
                        icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle',
                        class_name: 'success-notice'
                    });

                    $scope.CusDetails = {};
                }
                else {
                    $.gritter.add({
                        title: 'Failed!',
                        text: 'Failed to add a new customer. Please retry.',
                        time: '',
                        close_icon: 'l-arrows-remove s16',
                        icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle',
                        class_name: 'error-notice'
                    });
                }


            });
        }
    }
```

And finally the validation.js for validating above form

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#CustomerDetails").validate({

        debug:true,

        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {

            var place = element.closest('.input-group');

            if (!place.get(0)) {
                place = element;
            }

            if (error.text() !== '') {
                place.after(error);
            }
        },
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        rules: {
            cname: {
                required: true,

            },
            comname: {
                required: true
            },

            ctel: {
                required: true,
                min: 10
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            cname: {
                required: "Please enter customer name!"
            },
            comname: {
                required: "Please enter company name!"
            },
            ctel: {
                required: "Please enter telephone number",
                minlength: "Telephone number should be atleast 10 digits"
            }
        },
        highlight: function (label) {
            $(label).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        },
        success: function (label) {
            $(label).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            label.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

The error from debuggging from the built in function in validation says:
**Nothing selected, can't validate, returning nothing.**

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't the validation.js isn't getting called?
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no input button or submit in the form?

Comment: I can't see the ng-app or ng-controller in the html, is it missing or it's not in the snippet only ? can you provide the full html code

Comment: What you are doing is not very good idea to start with. Better approach would be to get rid of this plugin and jQuery all together and do it Angular way.

Comment: Hi @MayankPandey Added the submit code. Also ng-app is added inthe index.html page through the routes it will work. Also the controller is added for this page as well I just pasted the necessary code for the question :)